# Show radiuses of other buildings

Tags: banished

Is there a keyboard shortcut or ability to show the radius of other buildings (market, gathers, etc) while you are placing a new building? I haven't seen anything in the keyboard options and would like to see them for building layout and placement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you pin the buildings of interest, their radiuses will continue to display while you place your next building.

[image: Multiple radius of forester lodges]

Comment: Wow. Thank you. So simple of course I overlooked it.